# How to figure out why a computer is crashing?

Tags: kernel, shutdown

Every so often, my laptop will crash.  The screen will freeze, including the cursor, the lock lights (caps lock and the like) will turn off if they were on, though my battery, power, and wifi lights still work.  I'm not sure if it's a kernel panic, because sometimes it will just freeze, then the same sound it makes when I turn it off by the power button, and then a reboot.  Other times, I see a screen of text (not like the booting text) and then it reboots the same way.  I *think* I saw 'kernel' and 'panic' on different lines.  But I can't be sure.

Originally, I thought it was a heat issue because it stopped happening when I put my laptop on a cooling fan on a hard surface, and it only was happening when I visited a resource-intensive website.  Then I thought it was a memory issue because heat was taken care of, but memory was overflowing into the swap partition.  But now it's been crashing even when memory use is low and heat is not setting off alarms in psensor(I have alarms set to go off at 60C for any component, and I'm pretty sure it hasn't gotten to 80C since I stopped using my laptop on my lap).

Technically, this is not Ubuntu.  It is Debian 8.2; but all my other Debian questions are answered through askubuntu.  It's a Dell Inspiron 1520, originally with a WindowsXP os(we wiped the harddrive before installing Debian), and has 2Gb RAM.  However, I believe my question is about Linux in general, not a specific version of Ubuntu or Debian.

I don't what I need to check or how to check it, how to determine what's a kernel problem, etc.  Here's what I've heard I need to look at(scite only there for opening text files):

- scite /var/log/kern.log
- scite /etc/rsyslog.conf
- scite /etc/rsyslog.d/
- scite /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
- scite /var/log/syslog
- sudo /usr/sbin/mcelog > mcelog.out

Two or three of these are blank.

I wasn't able to isolate anything in the kern.log until recently, because I'd always just restart my computer.  This most recent time, I forced it to shutdown instead of riding through the panic.  And I've left it down for a few days.  The last thing from the day it last shut down was this:

```
Oct 17 22:51:27 darty kernel: [  299.816045] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

Everything before that is very repetitive, and is identical to things 5 minutes prior to the error.  (It's been shutting down within five minutes in some instances.)

syslog contains nothing from before today.

sudo /usr/sbin/mcelog > mcelog.out returns nothing, though the file contains a bunch of gobbeldygook; I'm assuming it's machine code or something.

So ... yeah.  I'm at a complete loss as to what to do to determine what the error is.  I can almost reliably reproduce it by doing certain things on the website CodinGame.com  (I know the age-old wisdom is "If it hurts, don't do it."  Well, the whole reason I have a computer is so I can do things like CodinGame.  The analogy from this to medical would be "Don't stand up and walk around.")  Again, it is not heat nor memory.  I've got sensors on both of those attached to the panel.

==Edit==
My cousin and I did run memtest86, after wiping the hard drive, before we installed any OS, from a dedicated memtest disk.  Oh, and the kernel version is 3.16.0-4-amd64  My cousin said that might matter, but I don't think it should for this question.

TL;DR: How does one find the right files to figure out why a computer is crashing?

Comment: It's probably your hardware.
Did you try running memtest86? It's on the installation media. Let it run overnight as just a couple of passes might miss the defect.

Comment: how big is your swap partition and what is your swappiness set at?

Comment: please direct your question to the proper forum http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have a very good point, even though I had not heard of that particular stack exchange before, and this one is most popular for linux questions.  Since I don't have the option to migrate the question directly, I'm going to copy it over and close this a little later, in case someone comes up with a REALLY good answer.

Comment: Oh, and my swap partition is almost 4Gb big, and sees no use until regular RAM is all gone, though when RAM calms down, swap is often still there until I exit the browser.  I had to look up how to find swappiness.... It's set at the default 60 right now.  And since about two weeks ago (there was a very resource-intensive contest at CodinGame that ended then), I haven't seen any swap used at all.